# Python Selenium Chrome Unable to locate element no such element

Tags: python, selenium, element, locate

Hello I just got hired in my first job as junior eng. (I printed a img).
I must program a robot that acess a webpage, login, and download a file which is located on a dynamic table, There are always 15 records.
Everyday they add one in the bottom of the table and remove the last one, organized by date.

I tried to use Time.Sleep() to wait the page to load completely and even used WebDriverWait and expected_conditions together to wait until it locates the element.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61Eli.png)
This is my code:

```
username_input = wdriver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="j_username"]').send_keys(user)
password_input = wdriver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="j_password"]').send_keys(password)
login_buttom = wdriver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="submit"]').click()

--url where the dynamic table is located
wdriver.get('https://jfbricks.sienge.com.br/sienge/8/index.html#/common/page/2590')

--I have to acess the 'a' element in html where the download link is located
element = wdriver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="linhaRow_14"]/td[4]/a')

I get this message:
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="linhaRow_14"]/td[4]/a"}

this is the section I must access: I have to catch the last updated date, and access <a > 
 to  download the file.

I tried to locate the table 'father' using 'tabelaRow' and also tried to locate the tr with id = 'linhaRow_14'
<table id="tabelaRow">
<tbody>
<tr id="linhaRow_14">
        <td class="spwCelulaGrid spwLinhaGridPar">
                <span tipo="DATE">06/07/2022</span>
            </td>
        <td class="spwCelulaGrid spwLinhaGridPar aR">
                <span tipo="DATE">Dados</span>
            </td>
        <td class="spwCelulaGrid spwLinhaGridPar alignCenter">
                
                    <a href="download_url"><img scr=...></a>
        </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Thank you guys.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Which element are you trying to locate/click? Update the question with the parent/ancestor element of the `<tr>`

Comment: I am trying to locate the anchor with the download link.

Comment: It seems to me there are 15 anchors and possibly all of them have a download link

Comment: I just edited the parent in my question :)

Comment: You haven't clarified which download link among the 15 available?

Comment: Hello!! I found what was happening. Basically the whole table was inside an iframe. This I ifram containing the download path that I needed, was carrying a whole new html inside itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys it took a while to find the error. Basically, in my case, this table was loaded inside an `iframe` element, the `xpath` from the element that I wanted was being searched in the `outerMost` parent element, but the `Xpath` is in fact inside the element of the second html.

Solution, use:
`wdriver.switch_to.frame('id_of_the_iframe_you_want_to_inspect')`

This function switches the focus to a specific frame.
you can pass other parameters to identify the `iframe` you must target to `SELENIUM` to inspect and find your element.

If your element is inside the `iframe`, `find_element` won't work until you switch the focus of it.
Example of this `iframe`

```
 <head>
 <body>
   <div>
     <main> 
       <iframe id="iFramePage"  scr="path.."
         ***this iframe carries another html 
           <html>
             <head> ...
                 ...
                <table>
                   <tr id="linhaRow_14">
               ... 
           ...
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use this extension on chrome: [paThor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pathor/dmfhmngimehgcjphehggckijghgdebhm) to locate elements. If node is not found, check your Xpath.
2. Check your window handles, If a new tab or popup is opened, you may not be checking the correct page.
3. If there are multiple elements inside the div use relative Xpath like this:

Relative:  `//*[@id="linhaRow_14"]//td[4]/a` or `//*[@id="linhaRow_14"]//td[4]//a`

Absolute: `/*[@id="linhaRow_14"]/td[4]/a`

Comment: Thanks HighHill, yes there was a popup but I close it and the same error still happening, I found out it is because the element I wanted to locate was inside an iframe.

Comment: It's nice but you didn't mention that the page contains an iframe. It would be more beneficial for you to write the questions more descriptively.